# Why is my second string replacement executing but the first isn't?

Tags: python, string

I am solving the following problem on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/

The idea is that our input is a string s, which contains brackets "(" or ")" or lower chase English characters.

And we need to remove the minimum number of brackets to ensure that s is 'valid'; and s is 'valid' if we have every "(" followed by ")" and we can have characters in the middle or on either side and that is fine.
But we cannot have ")" before "(" ; if so we need to remove ")" and we cannot end with "(", and if we do, we need to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
def minRemoveToMakeValid(s: str) -> str:
    count = 0
    back_brack = 0

    for char in s:
        if char == "(":
            count += 1

        elif count <= 0 and char == ")":
            back_brack += 1

        elif count > 0 and char == ")":
            count -= 1
    print(count)
    final_s = s.replace("(", "", count)

    final_s = s.replace(")", "", back_brack)

    return final_s
```

For `input= "))(("` ; I am supposed to produce `output= ""`

But because the `first final_s` is not executing, the output I get is `"(("`

For some reason, the `second 'final_s'` is executing fine, but the `first final_s` isn't? I cannot see why. And I know it is not executing because on my IDE it is greyed out saying it is not executing.

I added a `print()` statement to check that the count is indeed 2 at that point, so I can't see why the first 'final_s' doesn't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are executing. It's just that you always replace on `s`, thus you overwrite your first `final_s`

> And I know it is not executing because on my IDE it is greyed out saying it is not executing.

The warning you say is not "it's not executing", it's either variable not in use (because you never use the first value, just overwrite it) or statement has no effect.

Change this:

```
    final_s = s.replace("(", "", count)
    final_s = s.replace(")", "", back_brack)
```

Into this:

```
    final_s = s.replace("(", "", count)
    final_s = final_s.replace(")", "", back_brack)
```

or even this:

```
    final_s = s.replace("(", "", count).replace(")", "", back_brack)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is executing, however, it is redundant. Both lines that start final_s act on *s*.

Replacing the penultimate line as follows should do the trick:

```py
def minRemoveToMakeValid(s: str) -> str:
    count = 0
    back_brack = 0

    for char in s:
        if char == "(":
            count += 1

        elif count <= 0 and char == ")":
            back_brack += 1

        elif count > 0 and char == ")":
            count -= 1
    print(count)
    final_s = s.replace("(", "", count)

    final_s = final_s.replace(")", "", back_brack)

    return final_s
```